# Zend Framework Query with Joins

Tags: zend-framework, join, zend-db-table

I am trying to replicate this query using zend framework:

```
SELECT 
    activitytype.description, 
    activity.datecompleted

FROM
    clientactivity
INNER JOIN activity
    ON activity.activityID = clientactivity.activityid
INNER JOIN activitytype
    ON activitytype.activitytypeid = activity.activitytypeid

WHERE
    clientactivity.clientid = 100
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$select = $dbTable->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);

$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->where('clientactivity.clientid = ?', $clientID);

$select->join('activity', 'activity.activityid = clientactivity.activityid');
$select->join('activitytype', 'activitytype.activitytypeid = activity.activitytypeid');

$select->columns(array('activitytype.description', 'activity.datecompleted'));
```

I seem to be having problems with the columns option, it doens't seem to be limiting the columns and I am ending up with
clientactivity.* etc in the column list in the query.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of the $select->columns();

```
$select->from('activitytype.description', 'activity.datecompleted');
```

Reference - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html

**UPDATE:**

This example makes us of a generic database handler:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'username' => 'yourusername',
            'password' => 'somepassword',
            'dbname'   => 'yourdbname'
        ));

 $select = $db->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
 $select->from('tableName','fieldName')
         ->join('joinTable', 'joinTable.keyId = tableName.keyId',array())
         ->where('tableName.userId = ?', $userId);

 $resultSet = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

The key piece is the blank array at the end of the join statements that specifies no records to be returned from the joined table.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help, gives an error at first, when I make the fields an array and add null as the table name I get the fields in the list but still have the clientactivity.* etc. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,  Are you using Zend_Db_Table to creat $select?  Think this would have a bearing on the results with clientactivity being included by default.  I'll update the answer with a working piece of code I've just knocked up using Zend_Db_Select.

Comment: That’s got it, thanks!! I am assuming you can't do this kind of thing when using Zend_Db_Table.

Comment: @Martin As Zend_Db_Table represents a physical DB table in OOP and you are not selecting any columns from that table, it's not really a case of "you can't", more a case of "you shouldn't".

Comment: @Shimnon: hey! your little empty array() saved me!!